# Convert powershell azure command into CLI

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cli, az, azure-dns

I need to convert below into a cli command into a CLI command and need some help.

```
New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name www -RecordType A -ZoneName host.com -ResourceGroupName devdnsgroup -Ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "10.10.10.10")
```

I have started with:

```
az network dns record-set a add-record -g devdnsgroup -z host.com --ttl 3600
```

However I am unsure on how to accomplish the last part: `-DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "10.10.10.10")`

Here is my reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/a?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-dns-record-set-a-add-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the command [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-cli#create-a-dns-record)

```
az network dns record-set a add-record -g MyResourceGroup -z contoso.xyz -n www -a 10.10.10.10
```